# Filter with many optional parameters doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my code.
only when the first if statement (phoneNumber) is not null the query will work fine, but if the first if is null and other parmenters not null it will give me the entire table

```
public static List<AllMember> SearchMember(string phoneNumber, string fName, string lName, string Tz, string empNum, string email, string dbName)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DCardsDataContext(Organizations.GetConnectionStringByDbName(dbName)))
        {
            return db.AllMembers.Where(
                m =>
                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) ? true : phoneNumber == m.PhoneNumber &&
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(fName) ? true : fName == m.MemberFirstName &&
                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(lName) ? true : lName == m.MemberLastName &&
                      string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tz) ? true : Tz == m.TZ &&
                       string.IsNullOrEmpty(empNum) ? true : empNum == m.EmployeeNum &&
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) ? true :  email == m.Email 
                ).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Info($"error in SearchMember");
        Logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are either using Entity Framework or Linq to SQL. Please don't tag both if you are not using one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, that's almost certainly an error or parentheses and precedence rules - adding more parentheses should make it work "ok":

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) ? true : phoneNumber == m.PhoneNumber)
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fName) ? true : fName == m.MemberFirstName)
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lName) ? true : lName == m.MemberLastName)
...
```

But secondly, that's hugely inefficient - it tends to generate very expensive SQL. A better way is to compose the query based on what is actually needed *for your specific query*:

```
IQueryable<Whatever> query = db.AllMembers;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
    query = query.Where(m => m.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fName))
    query = query.Where(m => m.MemberFirstName == fName);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lName))
    query = query.Where(m => m.MemberLastName == lName);
// ...

var results = query.Take(maxCount).ToList();
```